# Creating a colour gradient around zero in filled.contour

Tags: r, colors, contour

I am new to R and am struggling to find an answer to what I thought would be a relatively common question. I am creating a world map of a variable using filled.contour. For example:

```
z=matrix(rnorm(7008),nrow=96)
x=seq(-176.25,180, by=3.75)
y=seq(-90,90, by=2.5)
filled.contour(x,y,z, plot.axes={axis(1); axis(2); map(add=TRUE, interior=FALSE)} )
```

In which x & y are longitude and latitude, and z is a data matrix. I have spent time applying my own colours and levels, however I want to have a gradient of colour with white assigned as zero. With negative number grading to dark blue and positive to dark red through green and yellow.

I have tried to use the color.scale function from the 'plotrix' package

```
cellcol=matrix(rep("#000000",7008),nrow=96) # replicating the size of my matrix z
cellcol[z>0]=color.scale(z[z>0], c(0,1,1),c(1,1,0),0) # values above zero grading to red 
cellcol[z<0]=color.scale(z[z<0], 0, 0,c(0,1)) # values below zero grading to blue
```

However now I am stuck. Is this the best way to go about doing this? If so how do I input this into the the filled.contour code above? I'm sure it is simple yet can't get it to work.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `color.scale` is not in the plotrix package?

Comment: Apologies I have edited and tried to make my question more reproducible

Comment: If your data are, like in your example centered around zero you can use `filled.contour(x,y,z, plot.axes={axis(1); axis(2)}, color.palette=colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue")))`, but I suppose they are not.

Comment: No I'm afraid not. Thanks for the advice below, I have done it in ggplot2 but assumed there must be a way for filled.contour

Comment: I managed to do it with filled.contour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only managed to achieve what you want using `ggplot2`.

You can try the following (I submerged the volcano data as an example):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

## Just an example, I subtract the mean to have positive and negative values for z 
dd <- volcano-mean(volcano)

## Creates a data.frame with columns x, y, z
dd <- melt(dd)
names(dd) <- c('x','y','z')

## Does the contour plot
d <- ggplot(dd, aes(x,y,z=z))
d + geom_tile(aes(fill=z))  + scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", high="red")
```

[image]

---

I wrote a small function that does what you want to achieve:

```
myFilled.contour <- function(x = seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(z)),
                             y = seq(0, 1, length.out = ncol(z)),
                             z, nlevels=30, ...) {
  ma <- max(abs(z))
  lvls <- seq(-ma, ma, length.out = nlevels)
  cols <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red")) (nlevels - 1)
  filled.contour(x, y, z, plot.axes={axis(1); axis(2)},
                 col=cols, levels=lvls, ...)
}
```

Using `filled.contour` and again the submerged volcano `dd`:

```
myFilled.contour(z=d)
```

[image]
Using your data:

```
myFilled.contour(x,y,z)
```

[image]

**Caveat:** The legend includes levels not used in the contour plot.

Hope it helps,

alex

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much for the help and time you have put into this. In the end I think I'm probably going to go back to ggplot2 as it is clearly more versatile, but just doesn't look as good!

Comment: As a quick question to save me some time, do you know how I add the world map as I have done with map(add=TRUE) for the filled.contour?

Comment: Check the ggmap package, I think it does what you want.